# Error: Expected ',' before this. validator: validate!(String value),

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety, null-safety

Hello I'm getting this error in flutter:

```
lib/shared/components/components.dart:41:35: Error: Expected ',' before this.
      validator: validate!(String value),
                                  ^^^^^
lib/modules/login/login_screen.dart:36:33: Error: The argument type 'String? Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function()?'.
                      validate: (String value){
                                ^
lib/shared/components/components.dart:41:35: Error: Getter not found: 'value'.
      validator: validate!(String value),
                                  ^^^^^
lib/shared/components/components.dart:41:27: Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
      validator: validate!(String value),
                          ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

components.dart code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget defaultButton(
    {double width = double.infinity,
      Color background = Colors.blue,
      double radius = 10.0,
      Function()? function,
      required String text,
      bool isUpperCase = true}) =>
    Container(
      height: 40.0,
      width: width,
      child: MaterialButton(
          onLongPress: () {},
          onPressed: function!() ,
          child: Text(
            isUpperCase ? text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(radius),
        color: background,
      ),
    );

Widget defaultFormFeild({
  required TextEditingController controller,
  required TextInputType type,
  void Function(String)? onSubmit,
  void Function(String)? onChange,
  required Function()? validate,
  required var label,
  required IconData prefix,
}) =>
    TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      keyboardType: type,
      onFieldSubmitted: onSubmit, //do null checking
      onChanged: onChange, //do null checking
      validator: validate!(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: label,
          prefixIcon: Icon(prefix),
          border: OutlineInputBorder()
      ),
    );
```

login_screen.dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:udemy_flutter/shared/components/components.dart';
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  var emailController = TextEditingController();
  var passController = TextEditingController();
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                      'Login',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  ),
                  defaultFormFeild(
                      controller: emailController,
                      label: 'Email',
                      prefix: Icons.email,
                      type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validate: (String value){
                        if(value.isEmpty != null){
                          return 'Email Cannot Be Empty';
                        }
                        return null;
                      }
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: passController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.lock
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.remove_red_eye,
                      )
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      print(value);
                    },
                    onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                      print(value);
                    },
                    validator: (value) {
                      if(value!.isEmpty){
                        return 'Password cannot be empty';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  defaultButton(
                    function: (){
                      print(emailController.text);
                      print(passController.text);
                    },
                    text: 'Login',
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  defaultButton(
                    text: 'ReGister',
                    function: () {
                      print('You have just clicked on register');
                    },
                    background: Colors.red,
                    isUpperCase: false
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Text('Don\'t you have an account?'),
                      TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text(
                        'Register Now'
                      ))
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***Can someone tell me where I am going wrong*** I'm new to the Flutter platform and I'm trying to build screens for various uses as I was having problems with Null safety and I managed to solve it, but I didn't know exactly what the problem with this code was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextFormField accepts FormFieldValidator? as a `validator`. The definition of the FormFieldValidator is:

```
typedef FormFieldValidator<T> = String? Function(T? value);
```

This doesn't match your definition of `Function()? validator`. You need to change your type to match the FormFieldValidator.

```dart
  void Function(String)? onChange,
  required Function()? validate,
  required var label,
```

will become

```dart
  void Function(String)? onChange,
  required String Function(String)? validate
  required var label,
```

Next, there is a second problem. You are executing this function before you assign it. It's unnecessary and causes type mismatch. In `defaultFormFeild` change the code to not execute the validator before passing it to the form field.

```dart
      onChanged: onChange, //do null checking
      validator: validate,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
```